# Java: Read certificates from windows store

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, x509certificate

It is possible to write a Java program to read one certificate (getting private and public key) stored in windows certificate store ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are on Java 6, you can use the MSCAPI keystore to read it. Just open your keystore like this,

```
      KeyStore msCertStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
```

Comment: Thanks. "Windows-MY" refers to ROOT\Personal. And what if i need to look for certificates in other location, for exemple ROOT\MyOwnFolder ?

Comment: No. You can't read arbitrary store with MSCAPI keystore. The only other store you can read is "WINDOWS-ROOT".